# Braintree result doesnt contain paymentMethod member

Tags: ios, braintree, applepay, braintree-sandbox

I've integrated Braintree in iOS, paypal and credit card work like a charm. I tried implementing apple pay ( added a merchant id , created an apple pay certificate etc) and can see the apple pay options.

**When selecting Apple pay**, the braintree result i get back as a response doesnt contain the `paymentMethod` member and subsequently i cant get a nonce as the nonce is a member of that in turn.

Anyone else stuck here as well? Cant find any documentation on this. The device seems to be able to perform payments.

```
PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork.visa, PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, PKPaymentNetwork.amex]); //returns true
```

*P.S: Using *BTDropInController* though it shouldnt make any difference.

P.S.2: This happens both on a simulator and a device*

Comment: Show some code maybe you missed something when creating payment request.

Comment: I probably havent as im using the BTDropInController to make the request and its supposed to do that for me. I dont really make the request myself in the other payment methods either i simply use BTDropInController

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Per the developer docs, this is [expected behavior](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/ios/v4#apple-pay). Selecting Apple Pay as the payment method in the Drop-in UI does not display the Apple Pay sheet or create a nonce – you will still need to do that at the appropriate time in your app. Use `BTApplePayClient` to tokenize the customer's Apple Pay information. For more information, check out Braintree's [Apple Pay Guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/client-side/ios/v4).

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems i was misguided on how far the Drop-in UI goes. +1